# Gmail filter: forward emails that arrive to Inbox to one email address, and emails that arrive to spam to another email address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Gmail filter: forward emails that arrive to Inbox to one email address, and emails that arrive to spam to another email address.

How can this be done?

I tried playing with filters with the conditions of in:spam and is:spam, but so far no success.

## EDIT: these are the XML (exported) rules I am trying:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
    <title>Mail Filters</title>
    <id>REPLACED</id>
    <updated>2023-01-17T06:50:47Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>REPLACED</name>
        <email>REPLACED</email>
    </author>
    <entry>
        <category term='filter'></category>
        <title>Mail Filter</title>
        <id>REPLACED</id>
        <updated>2023-01-17T06:50:47Z</updated>
        <content></content>
        <apps:property name='hasTheWord' value='deliveredto:a@one.com'/>
        <apps:property name='label' value='uniqueTag'/>
        <apps:property name='forwardTo' value='b@two.com'/>
        <apps:property name='sizeOperator' value='s_sl'/>
        <apps:property name='sizeUnit' value='s_smb'/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <category term='filter'></category>
        <title>Mail Filter</title>
        <id>REPLACED</id>
        <updated>2023-01-17T06:50:47Z</updated>
        <content></content>
        <apps:property name='doesNotHaveTheWord' value='label:uniqueTag'/>
        <apps:property name='label' value='spamTag'/>
        <apps:property name='forwardTo' value='c@two.com'/>
        <apps:property name='shouldNeverSpam' value='true'/>
        <apps:property name='sizeOperator' value='s_sl'/>
        <apps:property name='sizeUnit' value='s_smb'/>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: When you say "forward all mail", you mean a rule with: Has the Words deliveredto:info@mydomain.com ?

Comment: Well, doesn't work for me :( The emails in the spam folders stay in spam and are not forwarded..

Comment: Thank you, not sure I understand your comment. You said, "Nothing that arrives will be affected.", but that's the whole point of filters. The question says "forward emails that arrive to Inbox to one email address, and emails that arrive to spam to another email address.". Yes, I am talking about new messages (are there other options besides new messages??)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am talking about new email arriving: I would like regular non-spam to be fowarded to b@two.com and email that is marked as spam to be forwarded to c@two.com - that's it. I edited the question with the XML as per your request. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: Sorry Nathan, can't get the SPAM to forward.

Comment: Thank you. Just received an answer from Google that it is indeed impossible... :( Pitty.